# ruby map find_each can't add to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have 2 Models: Document and Keywords. They are habtm in relation to each other and they both `accepts_nested_attributes_for` each other so I can create a nested form. That works well.

So in params, I have

```
"document"=>{"book_id"=>"1", "keywords"=>{"keywords"=>"term, administration, witness "}, ...
```

In the controller I put the keywords in a separate array like this :

```
q = params[:document][:keywords].fetch(:keywords).split(",")
```

This works well too.

What I now need to do, is get the keywords ids and put them in an array. Each element of that array will populate the join table.

I've tried this :

```
a = Array.new
q.each do |var|
  id =  Keyword.select(:id).find_by keyword: var
  a << id
  id
end
```

But, this only answers `[#<Keyword id: 496>, nil, nil]`, although the server log shows that all 3 SQL requests are executed and they are correct.

I have also tried this :

```
a = Array.new
q.map do |e| 
  Keyword.where(motcle: e).select(:id).find_each do |wrd| 
    a << wrd.id
  end
end
```

Then again, this only return the FIRST id of the keyword, although the server log shows that all 3 SQL requests are executed.

What I'm trying to get is `a = [496, 367, 2398]`

So I have 2 questions :

1/ Why are the ids not added to the array, despite the server executing all SQL requests ?

2/ How to write in rails a request  would be

```
SELECT  "motclefs"."id" FROM "motclefs" WHERE "motclefs"."motcle" in ('déchéances','comtesse') ORDER BY "motclefs"."id";
```

Thanks !

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to pass the keyword **ids** from the form to your controller?

Comment: Yes, that would be easier, but I can't see how as the keywords get fetched through the jquery-ui autocomplete function in json. So what I would need there is something like `"keywords"=>{"term"=>"496", "administration" =>"966", "witness"=>"1046"}`

Comment: You just need `"keyword_ids" => [496, 966, 1046]`

Comment: No I don't, since I must show the words in the form and the ids need to get send to the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned value is an object of Keyword. You need to get the id attribute of the object. eg:

```
id =  Keyword.where(keyword: var).select(:id).first.id
```

A better way to get all the ids would be

```
a = Keyword.where(keyword: ['term', 'administration', 'witness']).pluck(:id) 
# I think this might answer your second question.
```

Comment: Thanks Santhosh, but how and where do you integrate that second piece of code ?

Comment: `id =  Keyword.select(:id).find_by(keyword: var).id` returns `undefined method id`.

Comment: How are you using the Array of ids (`a`)?  The second statement will just populate the array

Comment: The undefined method could be because one of the keywords doesnt exist

Comment: the keywords do exist as they get populated into the form via jquery autocomplete. I checked the SQL queries that are shown in the server log.

Comment: Thanks Santhosh ! The other little bug I have was the whitespace that I needed to add in `split(", ")`. This did cause the array to contain corrupted form data and therefore `.id` didn't work. All corrected :)

Comment: You should use [`ids`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-ids) instead of `pluck(:id)`

Comment: For your second problem, maybe before call the **split** method, you can do this on your string:

    your_string.gsub(/[[:space:]]+/, '').split(',')

the `/[[:space:]]+/`regex find [every whitespace character (\[:blank:\], newline, carriage return, etc.)][1]

[documentation][2] for **gsub**


  [1]: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html
  [2]: http://apidock.com/ruby/String/gsub

Comment: @Stefan. Didnt know about that method. Thanks